# I am trying to get a complete worldmap without any repeating to autosize to a div using gmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-maps

so I tried autofitting the map by using corners on the far corners of the world but that didn't help. What I keep getting is repeating world map. I am using gmap3.js with wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  var markersToBeAdded  = [];
   markersToBeAdded.push([-75, -90]);
   markersToBeAdded.push([75, 90]);
   markersToBeAdded.push([-75, 90]);
   markersToBeAdded.push([75, -90]);
  // markersToBeAdded.push([-90, 180]);
   //markersToBeAdded.push([90, 180]);

    $("#fullmap").gmap3({
         action: 'addMarkers', 
                        markers: markersToBeAdded,
                        //to autofit the map
                        callback:function(m)
                        { //m will be the array of markers
                          var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                          for(var i=0;i<m.length;++i)
                          {
                            bounds.extend(m[i].getPosition());
                          }
                          try{
                               var map=$(this).gmap3({action:'get'});
                                   map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                   map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter())
                              }catch(e){}
                        },
 map:{
    options:{

     draggable:false,   

     zoom:2
    }



 }

});
$("#fullmap").width(($(window).width())+'px').height((($(window).height()-150))+'px').gmap3(); 
//_h = $('#gmap').height();
//$("#fullmap").css("width", _h);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the minimum zoom level you will allow is 0, make your map 256 pixels wide, if the minimum zoom you will allow is 1, make your map 512 pixels wide, if the minimum zoom you will allow is 2, make your map 1024 pixels wide.

Google maps only supports discrete zoom levels, if those sizes don't work for you, you are probably out of luck.

I don't know how to change the minimum zoom in gmap3 with wordpress (looks to be fairly obvious though); in the Google  Maps API v3, you do it with the [minZoom mapOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

Comment: That does work but I was hoping to get a bigger map. is there no way to stretch the map like pixel for pixel.